# Beautiful Soup - Extract data only contain td tag (without tag like div, id, class....)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Beautiful Soup, and I have data like this, which contain 3 set of user data(for this case).

I want to get all the information for each USER_ID and save to database.

- User ID
- Title
- Content
- PID(not every user has this row)
- Date
- URL

```
<table align="center" border="0" style="width:550px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 11111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: aaa</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 22222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: bbb</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 33333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: ccc</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>PID：</strong><strong>ABCDE</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://ccc.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is, 
All the data are inside td only, and do not contain div name and no parent tag. I can't separate into 3 set of data.

I have try the following code, it can find all the USER_ID, but I don't know how to get other data for each USER_ID

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile("^USER_ID"))
for item in p:
   title = item.find_next_siblings('td') # <--- return empty
   ...
```

I'm using 
python 3.6 
django 2.0.2

Comment: Check below answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from more_itertools import split_when

data = """<table align="center" border="0" style="width:550px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 11111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: aaa</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 22222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: bbb</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 33333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: ccc</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>PID：</strong><strong>ABCDE</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://ccc.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

target = soup.find("table", align="center")

goal = [item.text for item in target.select(
    "td", text=re.compile("^USER_ID")) if item.text.strip() != '']


final = list(split_when(goal, lambda _, y: y.startswith("USER")))

print(final)  # list of lists

for x in final:  # or loop
    print(x)
```

Output

```
[['USER_ID 11111', 'string_a', 'content: aaa', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com'], ['USER_ID 22222', 'string_b', 'content: bbb', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com'], ['USER_ID 33333', 'string_c', 'content: ccc', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'PID：ABCDE', 'URL：https://ccc.com']]
```

And

```
['USER_ID 11111', 'string_a', 'content: aaa', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com']
['USER_ID 22222', 'string_b', 'content: bbb', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com']
['USER_ID 33333', 'string_c', 'content: ccc', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'PID：ABCDE', 'URL：https://ccc.com']
```

Comment: I got this error.     goal = [item.text for item in target.select("td", text=re.compile("^USER_ID")) if item.text.strip() != '']
TypeError: select() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

Comment: @user3114168 which `bs4` version you are running ? looks like you are using old version which not supporting `CSS SELECTORS`, you can change `select` to be `findAll`

Comment: I'm using "bs4 version 4.6.0", After changed "select" to "findAll". For print(final), it only get the USER_ID like this... [['USER_ID 11111'], ['USER_ID 22222'], ['USER_ID 33333']]

Is there any I made it wrong?

Comment: @user3114168 you've to upgrade your version to the latest one which is `4.9.0`, `pip install bs4 --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Try following code which will identify `find_all_next('td')` and check with if condition to break the `dataset`.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<table align="center" border="0" style="width:550px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 11111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: aaa</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 22222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: bbb</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://aaa.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">USER_ID 33333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">string_c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>content: ccc</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>date：</strong>2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>PID：</strong><strong>ABCDE</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><strong>URL：https://ccc.com</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

final_list=[]
for item in soup.find_all('td',text=re.compile("USER_ID")):
    row_list=[]
    row_list.append(item.text.strip())
    siblings=item.find_all_next('td')
    for sibling in siblings:
        if "USER_ID" in sibling.text:
            break
        else:
            if sibling.text.strip()!='':
               row_list.append(sibling.text.strip())
    final_list.append(row_list)

print(final_list)
```

**Output**:

```
[['USER_ID 11111', 'string_a', 'content: aaa', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com'], ['USER_ID 22222', 'string_b', 'content: bbb', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com'], ['USER_ID 33333', 'string_c', 'content: ccc', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'PID：ABCDE', 'URL：https://ccc.com']]
```

---

If you want each list to print try this.

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('td',text=re.compile("USER_ID")):
    row_list=[]
    row_list.append(item.text.strip())
    siblings=item.find_all_next('td')
    for sibling in siblings:
        if "USER_ID" in sibling.text:
            break
        else:
            if sibling.text.strip()!='':
               row_list.append(sibling.text.strip())
    print(row_list)
```

**Output**:

```
['USER_ID 11111', 'string_a', 'content: aaa', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com']
['USER_ID 22222', 'string_b', 'content: bbb', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'URL：https://aaa.com']
['USER_ID 33333', 'string_c', 'content: ccc', 'date：2020-05-01 00:00:00 To 2020-05-03 23:59:59', 'PID：ABCDE', 'URL：https://ccc.com']
```